# Setting a default CPU Frequency in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

How do I get Ubuntu to select a default `cpufreq` on boot? These are the frequencies my CPU has available:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
2300000 2200000 2000000 1800000 1000000
```

I want 2200000 set as default. I have learnt that running the following command will do just that:

```
$ cpufreq-selector -f 2200000
```

My question is how do I get that to run on boot and stay default?

Comment: This is a question for http://www.superuser.com/

Comment: (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/)

Comment: I agree. voting to close

Comment: Also, to answer Jim's question: http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/

Comment: You should change the title to something more appropriate.

Comment: Why?  You get the best results with the default ondemand policy.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do this in Ubuntu is:

- Copy /etc/init.d/skeleton to *scriptname* and edit it to your needs.
- Make it executable.
- Install your script into the Debian runlevels via this command.

> sudo update-rc.d *scriptname* defaults

- Check that links to your script exist in other runlevels, e.g rc2.d, rc3.d. You can also confirm that this script is properly installed through the *Administration->Bootup Manager* GUI.

Check */etc/init.d/README* for more detailed instructions and links to the specification document. You can also impose finer control over which run-levels your scripts runs on, and the priority it should get called at:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d dummy defaults
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dummy ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc1.d/K20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc6.d/K20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc2.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc3.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc4.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc5.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
$ sudo update-rc.d -f dummy remove
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/dummy ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20dummy
   /etc/rc1.d/K20dummy
   /etc/rc2.d/S20dummy
   /etc/rc3.d/S20dummy
   /etc/rc4.d/S20dummy
   /etc/rc5.d/S20dummy
   /etc/rc6.d/K20dummy

$ sudo update-rc.d -n -f dummy start 20 2 3 4 5 .
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dummy ...
   /etc/rc2.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc3.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc4.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc5.d/S20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
$ sudo update-rc.d -n -f dummy stop 20 0 6 .
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dummy ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
   /etc/rc6.d/K20dummy -> ../init.d/dummy
```

**Edit:** The first step initially said to follow a template I provided with the answer, but I later realized that a standardized template exists so I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

(UBUNTU 9.10)  There is already a script titled "ondemand" in the init.d that sets the cpu frequency, and if yours is not set after it does it's magic then yours will not work.  An easy fix is if you edit the line that says "echo -n ondemand > $CPUFREQ" and change ondemand to powersave it will save you the headache of making your own.

Comment: Or disable ondemand on startup and copy it to a new name appropriate to your situation and then enable that one.

Comment: do this: sudo update-rc.d ondemand defaults

Comment: Powersave doesn't actually save power, and often uses more than ondemand.

Answer (score 1):

On a simple case like this one I would add a line with the command to /etc/rc.local, before the "exit 0".

For more complex init scripts, follow nagul answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to execute your command, then put the script in your /etc/init.d directory.

It'll then be run at startup

Comment: Scripts in /etc/init.d are not automatically executed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

```
1. edit /etc/rc.local :  sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
2. add the line berofe exit 0:  cpufreq-selector -f 2200000 [add sudo if it need]
3. save the file and exit
4. you can run the for current session : sudo /etc/rc.local
5. From next session this script will automatically run
```