# Remotely make the computer beep on built-in speaker

Tags: linux

How can I remotely (SSH) make my Linux Computer Beep (built-in speaker, as there are no external ones)? I have ubuntu 9.04 and can install extra packages if need be. This would be good for finding a certain box if you have more than one standing around and forgot which IP is which box.

Comment: I hope your question isn't really this cartoon at work: http://xkcd.com/530/

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep || http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313939/how-to-emit-a-beep-on-my-computer-while-running-a-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 this question is older than any of those.

Comment: @wsd I did not imply duplicate and the current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newbie Google keywords on the title.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/console"
```

You may have to load the kernel module for the built-in speaker first (e.g. if the module was blacklisted from auto-loading):

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

Comment: This worked while the beep command did not. I just set this to run on a coworkers machine. for i in `seq 1 10000`; do echo -e '\a' > /dev/console; sleep 1; done

Comment: Didn't make a sound.

Comment: This works well on CentOS / RHEL, I couldn't find any beep packages.

Comment: @NickStinemates Make sure you have a PC speaker on your motherboard

Comment: This is the easiest solution! Also, sorry for only accepting 9 years late.

Answer (score 14):

first:

```
modprobe pcspkr
```

then solutions from topic, like

```
ssh user@host
beep
```

Comment: (As for the `modprobe`: see [how to get beep working?](http://superuser.com/questions/232672/how-to-get-beep-working/232692#232692) for some details.)

Comment: I needed to `sudo modprobe pcskr`

Answer (score 7):

From the **beep** man page on my Ubuntu machine:

> IOCTL WACKINESS
>
> Some  users will encounter a
>   situation where beep dies with a
>   complaint    from ioctl().  The reason
>   for this, as Peter Tirsek was nice
>   enough  to    point  out  to  me,
>   stems from how the kernel handles
>   beep’s attempt to    poke at (for
>   non-programmers: ioctl is a  sort  of 
>   catch-all  function    that  lets  you
>   poke at things that have no other
>   predefined poking-at    mechanism) the
>   tty, which is how it beeps.  **The 
>   short  story  is,  the    kernel
>   checks that either:**
>
> - **you are the superuser**
> - **you own the current tty**
>
> What  this means is that root can
>   always make beep work (to the best of 
>   my knowledge!), and that any local
>   user can make beep work, BUT **a  non-root  remote user cannot use beep in
>   it’s natural state.**

This could well be the reason why beep refuses to work remotely. You can check if this is the root cause by invoking **ssh** with the **-t** option, which forces pseudo-tty allocation.

A less desirable solution would be to create a wrapper script that executes beep, and [grant this script root permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/26271/how-can-i-pass-root-password-to-a-script). If executing this script over **ssh** duly produces a beep, you'll know that the issue is the lack of a controlling terminal.

Comment: In sudoers I put
'User_Alias BEEPERS = myname  
  Cmnd_Alias BEEP = /usr/bin/beep  
  BEEPERS ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: BEEP'
You still have to use sudo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
ssh user@remote-machine
sudo sh -c "echo -e '\a' > /dev/tty1"
```

Note that the following would not work. It fails before even prompting for the `sudo` password because the (`bash`) shell is doing the redirection, and that shell still runs as the normal user, not as `root`:

```
ssh user@remote-machine
sudo echo -e '\a' > /dev/tty1
-bash: /dev/tty1: Permission denied
```

```
ls -la /dev/tty1
crw------- 1 root root 4, 1 2009-09-28 16:33 /dev/tty1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just type

```
ssh user@remote-machine
beep
```

Tested on Ubuntu Desktop 8.x, this will beep on the remote server, even if no local session on that server is active (thus: even if the GNOME login screen is shown on the monitor attached to the server).

Have a look at

```
man beep
```

for more details. On Debian/Ubuntu, the beep package has to be installed and the speakers must not be muted.

Comment: I wonder why you wrote *"the speakers must not be muted"*. My Ubuntu **Desktop** box has no sound drivers installed, and indeed both `beep` and the `echo` options all use my built-in speaker. Though `man beep` clearly states *"beep the pc speaker any number of ways"*, I have not verified what happens if one has sound drivers installed.

Comment: At least on my pc I can mute the speakers with gnome-volume-control. And since I can't stand the beeping, I usually do.

Comment: So, then `beep` does not use the built-in speaker on your system? Or does the volume control (which is disabled on my Ubuntu box) also control the built-in speaker? Might be fun to see if the `echo` solutions behave different than.

Comment: gnome-volume-control can be used to control the built-in speaker separately. What do you mean by disabled? What happens when you run gnome-volume-control from a command line?

Comment: Sorry, just wiped out that 10.8 install. Disabled as in: no sound drivers installed, and therefore a stop-sign on top of the sound-icon in the GNOME menu.

Answer (score 3):

This command will do the trick:

```
modprobe pcspkr; echo -e "\a" > /dev/console;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a remote command to the remote machine:

> rsh hostname /usr/bin/echo '\a' 
> or 
> ssh
>   user@remotehost /usr/bin/echo '\a'

Comment: Wouldn't one need the redirection to some remote terminal like Thomas suggested, to get the remote server to beep, rather than the local SSH client?

Comment: One can also do : echo "\a" > 'tty'.

Comment: `echo -e "\a" > /dev/tty` surely would beep on the SSH client, not on the built-in speaker on the server :-) `tty0`, `tty1` and `console` seem to work, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could simply run the following once:

```
chmod o+x `which beep`
```

This will allow all users to use the beep executable, which probably is safe enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This all works perfect after logging in and opening a tty device.
When for instance you want a beep from rc.local
to know when your linux machine is ready booting, like a intel nuc,
run this script /root/bin/boot-complete.sh from /etc/rc.d/rc.local :

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is /root/bin/boot-complete.sh

/sbin/modprobe pcspkr
/bin/sleep 1
/usr/bin/aumix -p 75
echo -e '\a' > /dev/tty1 2>&1
/bin/sleep 1
echo -e '\a' > /dev/tty1 2>&1

exit 0
```