# how to get beep working?

Tags: bash, fedora

I have a laptop, I've installed the *beep* package. I turned every sound to full, and I do this:

```
$ beep
```

But I can't hear any beeping sound. What am I missing?
I just need to run the beep when a script is finished.

Comment: If all else fails, then maybe the `echo -e '\a' > /dev/console` alternatives from [Remotely make the computer beep on built-in speaker](http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker) can help.

Comment: I've corrected the spelling and formatting. You don't need a `<br>` after every line. Press Enter twice or include two spaces at the end of a line.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu had an issue where some installs would beep on shutdown causing much annoyance.  Their solution was to blacklist pcspkr for all installs.  That may be what Fedora did.  Take a look through your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist (or Fedora equivalent) to see if it has an entry and try running `modprobe pcspkr` to make sure it's installed.

Comment: Nice, that might explain why `modprobe pcspkr` was mentioned in [an unrelated question](http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker/219503#219503) too!

Answer (score 3):

As of Fedora 17, I had to install `xkbset` and run `xkbset b` to enable the Audible Bell as it was disabled by default.  (That, and make sure the kernel module `pcspkr` is loaded.  The beep rpm puts a `/etc/modprobe.d/beep.conf` in place - you'll want to un-comment the appropriate line in that and/or run `modprobe pcspkr` if you haven't already.)

I hope that helps,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

Many terminal applications have the option of turning off the beep sound. Look in you terminal's settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment at an answer at [Remotely make the computer beep on built-in speaker](https://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker/47584#47584):

> gnome-volume-control can be used to control the built-in speaker separately.

So, maybe the volume level is tuned down?