# how to get beep working?

Tags: bash, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get beep working?](https://superuser.com/questions/232672/how-to-get-beep-working)

I have a laptop, i installed the "beep" package. I turned every sound to full, and i:

$ beep
$ 

but i can't hear any "beeping" sound. What am I missing?

I just need to run the "beep" when a script is finished.

Thank you for any links/howtos! :\

Comment: There's no need to post the same question *three times*.

Answer (score 2):

Does the computer your working on have a pc-speaker for emitting the beep? Please remember that beep doesn't use the sound card, it uses the cheap speaker which should be hooked up to the motherboard. If you want a sound after a script continues, your best bet is to find a wav file with a beep in it, and run `mplayer beep.wav`.

Comment: +1 many computers just don't have a beeper!