# how to get beep working?

Tags: bash, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get beep working?](https://superuser.com/questions/232672/how-to-get-beep-working)

I have a laptop, i installed the "beep" package. I turned every sound to full, and i:

```
$ beep
$
```

but i can't hear any "beeping" sound. What am I missing?

I just need to run the "beep" when a script is finished.

Thank you for any links/howtos! :\

Comment: Try just `printf "\a"` ? When testing this one, make sure your terminal isn't set to use 'visual bell'.

Comment: Did you place the cable correctly? And did you turn on your speaker?

Comment: @sarnold: One difference is that the terminal bell will beep locally while a `beep` would be heard wherever the host is. For example, if you're ssh'd from a PC to a server, the terminal bell will ring on the PC, but `beep` might ring perhaps thousands of miles away.

Comment: You don't need to post the same question *three times*.