# How to prompt (gui) and use root password on a script?

Tags: passwords, shell-script, kde-4

I would like run a script of mine that need some root privilegies on a gui way.

For example, a simple script could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
clementine
sudo shutdown -h 00:00
```

The first line opens the clementine music player (and I don't want root privilegies to open it) and the second will halt the computer on a specific time.

I would like run the script using `Alt+F2` and a dialog ask the root password to me when it is needed.

How to do this?

Comment: Wait...replacing `sudo` with `kdesudo` should work just fine.

Comment: @Bobby, I tried `Alt+F2` typed `sudo` with the script localization and hit Return. Clementine opened, but the shutdown no (didn't appear nothing in system monitor)=/...

Comment: I say it again: replacing `sudo` with `kdesudo` *in the simple script you posted* did not work?

Comment: In the question [`How can I pass Root Password to a script`](http://superuser.com/questions/26271/how-can-i-pass-root-password-to-a-script) I can see something that looks like what I'm needing, but I didn't know how can I use this to perform what I need.

Comment: @Bobby, nice idea. Well just put `kdesudo shutdown -h 00:00` instead `sudo shutdown -h 00:00` doesn't work. Maybe is the command `shutdown -h 00:00` isn't made by just one parameter. But is almost^^

Comment: @Bobby, Yeah! Nice. Works. Change to `kdesudo "shutdown -h 00:00"` works. Please write this as answer that I will embrace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kdesudo <Your command>`:

```
#!/bin/sh
clementine
kdesudo "shutdown -h 00:00"
```

Comment: @Bobby, if you put a similar answer I will embrace it instead of this answer of mine. Thx. Cya.