# Tweaks on nvidia-settings only working when the program is opened

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I have two monitors. The master one (17") is 1yo, and the secondary (15") is really old, like 4yo.
This old screen is having problems displaying colors... They are a little bit darker, what is a problem when I'm viewing pics.

I have a GeForce 9800, so I changed some settings inside `nvidia-settings`, that fit better with this second screen.
But those settings just are applied when I first open `nvidia-settings`. First time I configured this, it worked. I turned off computer, next day turned it on, and screen is dark again. As soon as I open `nvidia-settings` again, the screens get lighter again!

How can I make those settings permanent and loaded at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can run nvidia-settings on the command line, like so:

```
nvidia-settings --config=~/.nvidia-settings --load-config-only
```

Try and get this working on the command line. Once it is ready, you can just add this to run at boot. Check the answers juanjux and I gave to this question on [how to add a script to run at boot](https://superuser.com/questions/21767/setting-a-default-cpu-frequency-in-ubuntu).

Note, this will enable the script to run at boot, and not just when the GDM/KDE graphical environment starts up.

Comment: I think your answer do exactly what I need. But somehow when I run this command it throws me thousands of errors, all about 'anything could be assigned (no display connection)'. But if I simply open the program, it works ='(