# Swap Keyboard Layouts automatically in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use a notebook with a USA alternative international (former us international) layout and  a usb Microsoft Curve keyboard with Brazilian layout when at my desk.

What I would like is to switch layouts automatically when the usb keyboard is detected, instead of going to preferences manually every time I leave the desk. Is there such a way in ubuntu 9.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

There are three components to the solution that would let you swap keyboard layouts:

1. Detect when the keyboard is plugged in/out
2. Detect the layout on the keyboard
3. Set the layout of your system to match the keyboard layout.

**1. Detect when the keyboard is plugged in/out**

All hardware changes are sent on the [D-Bus message bus daemon](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).

> D-Bus is a message bus system, a simple way for applications to talk to one another. In addition to interprocess communication, D-Bus helps coordinate process lifecycle; it makes it simple and reliable to code a "single instance" application or daemon, and to launch applications and daemons on demand when their services are needed.
>
> ***D-Bus supplies both a system daemon (for events such as "new hardware device added" or "printer queue changed") and a per-user-login-session daemon (for general IPC needs among user applications).***

You can monitor the events sent on the D-Bus via the ***dbus-monitor*** command:

```
dbus-monitor --system #show all events
dbus-monitor --system --profile 'interface=org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager' # filter: only events sent by Hal
dbus-monitor --system --profile 'interface=org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager, member=DeviceAdded' # filter: only DeviceAdded events sent by Hal
```

Plug in your keyboard, and watch the messages go by. That should give you an idea of the filter you need to detect a keyboard being plugged in or out. You'll also need to get familiar with the [dbus-monitor](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-monitor) usage in more detail.

**2. Detect the layout of the keyboard**

Once the keyboard is plugged into the system, [HAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29)[(Hardware Abstraction Layer)](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) configures it. You can retrieve this info using the ***hal-get-property*** command once you have identified the key you need. For example, on my system:

```
$ hal-get-property --udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_KBD_port_logicaldev_input --key "input.xkb.layout"
gb
$ hal-get-property --udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_KBD_port_logicaldev_input --key "input.xkb.model"
pc105
```

Look at this answer for a detailed explanation of how to get values from HAL:  [setting up process profiles on ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/31446/setting-up-process-profiles-on-ubuntu/31553#31553). I think the D-Bus message might give you the configured HAL node for the connected device, but I'm not certain. If not, you know that it will be in either of two places - corresponding to one of two keyboards.

**3. Select the layout of your system to match the keyboard layout**

joe already pointed out [how you can do this using xmodmap](https://superuser.com/questions/46841/how-to-swap-keyboard-layouts-automatically-in-ubuntu/46852#46852).

Comment: good tips. I'll take a look into this and post my findings

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this . But this is my work around i used to solve  (switch from us to uk )

```
sudo xmodmap /usr/share/xmodmap/xmodmap.uk
```

Comment: I guess this would help in a script, but the important part is how do I detect they keyboard being plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this might be possible using some HAL-directives.

However, you don't need to go to Preferences each time you want to switch layouts. Why don't you simply add the "Keyboard Indicator" applet to your panel? It's only one mouse-click then.

Comment: That's what I currently do. But strangely enough the applet works on a per app setup. So it may use the USA layout for an app and still use the BRA setup for another until I click it. Don't know if this is the normal behavior though.

Comment: This can be configured from the Keyboard preferences: System -> Preferences -> Keyboard, switch to the "Layouts" tab and untick "Separate layout for each window".

Comment: Wow, I must have my eyes checked! That's correct, thanks. :)